# Can I set ConnectionLeaseTimeout for ServicePoint in the application configuration file?

Tags: .net, dotnet-httpclient

I am using a .NET HttpClient from my application to access a web service. The problem is that the web service is accessed through a ISP load balancer and the application is already installed at the customer (can't updated right now). If the load balancer changes to another ISP, the connection is kept alive and the request will timeout.

Can I set ConnectionLeaseTimeout for ServicePoint in the application configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: I think you're out of luck.

You can configure some global defaults using the [`<servicePointManager>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/servicepointmanager-element-network-settings) configuration element (`configuration/system.net/settings/servicePointManager`). Unfortunately the connection lease timeout doesn't seem to have changeable default.
Also, there seems to be no way to perform any of the settings for specific endpoints through configuration.

Perhaps the web service you're accessing could impose some kind of limit to how long the connection is kept open. If you think about it, it would make sense for them to control that policy, since they are load balancing their service.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can specify ConnectionLeaseTimeout in a config. But, you also have to read this value and apply it. You also mentioned you can't update your app so I'm not sure how this info is going to help you.

Please refer [here](https://github.com/NimaAra/Easy.Common/blob/master/Easy.Common/RestClient.cs) for a code example. Line number 550 and look for ConnectionLeaseTimeout.